# 'identity' requires Google Chrome trunk channel or newer, and this is the canary channel

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to play with Packaged Apps and the Identity API on latest Google Canary (Mac), however, when loading my app I get the following error: "'identity' requires Google Chrome trunk channel or newer, and this is the canary channel."

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled “Experimental Extension APIs” in `chrome://flags`? That’s what http://developer.chrome.com/apps/experimental.html says to do.

Comment: This answer is correct. The identity API is in stable, but the newest parts of it are still in experimental. The error message is incorrect, and we need to improve it. I filed https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243110.